# Is $f: [5,8] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = \cos^3(x + 1)$ uniformly continuous?

Tags: uniform-continuity

Let $f: [5,8] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x) = \cos^3(x + 1)$. Then $f$ is uniformly continuous if for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $x,y \in [5,8]$ and $|x-y| < \delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$.

I am attempting to find a $\delta > 0$ to show that $|f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$.

Suppose $|x-y| < \delta = ?$ and $x,y \in [5,8]$. Then $|f(x)-f(y)| = |\cos^3(x + 1)-\cos^3(y + 1)|$.

Using the trigonometric identity $\cos^3a = \frac{\cos 3a + 3\cos a}{4}$, I could write $|f(x)-f(y)|$ as

$\frac{|\cos(3x+3) + 3\cos(x+1) - \cos(3y+3) - 3\cos(y+1)|}{4}$ = $\frac{|\cos(3x+3) - \cos(3y+3) + 3[\cos(x+1) - \cos(y+1)]|}{4}$

But up to here I am a bit stuck since I am not sure how to show that this is less than $\epsilon$, using the fact that $|x-y| < \delta$.

Comment: Hint: Is the derivative bounded?

Comment: I guess you aren't allowed to use Cantor's theorem which says that a continuous function defined on a compact interval is uniformly continuous?

Comment: Hint 2: Use the formula you have for $|f(x)-f(y)|$ as scratch work to *figure* out what $\delta$ should be.  Then prove the statement using your formula.

Comment: I believe I could use Cantor's theorem, although this was covered in a later chapter in my notes. But this will definitely make the problem much easier.

Answer (score 2):

Hint 1: If you've seen compactness, you can just appeal to that, which will make the problem easier.

Hint 2: If not, rather than using the trig identity, use $(f^3 - g^3) = (f - g)(f^2 + gf + g^2)$.

Comment: Suppose I use the fact that $[5,8]$ is compact. If $f$ is continuous, then $f$ has to be uniformly continuous by the theorem. Now, all that's left to show is that $f$ is continuous. I'm having some problems with showing this though, using the standard definition of continuity.

Comment: @Outlier got it. If you're not allowed to break it into pieces and use the fact that compositions of continuous functions are continuous, polynomials are continuous, trig functions are continuous, etc., then you'll still have to use the factorization, just you can be a bit less careful about the quantifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use the *Mean value inequality*?
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\le M\,|x-y|,$$
where $M$ is an upper bound for $\;|f'(c)|=3\cos^2\mkern-3muc\mkern3mu|\sin c| $.